# apache domain and subdomains in different folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to setup an apache configuration so that:

1. `domain.com` & `www.domain.com` point to folder `/var/www/domain.com/root`
2. other subdomains `*.domain.com` point to folder `/var/www/domain.com/other`

I have already this configuration that solve problem 1.
What do i need to change for make step 2 work?

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80 >
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/root
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</VirtualHost>
```

best,
FA

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.10:80 >
    ServerName subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/other

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
</VirtualHost>
```

after the `VirtualHost` container that you already have.